# How do I isolate $y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In the equation $kx - 3y = 10$, how do I isolate the $y$ component? I forgot how to do basic algebra and I am taking a calculus course, lol. I'm not sure if you multiply or subtract, I think you look at the sign next to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the steps
\[ kx-3y=10 \]
\[ kx-3y +3y=10+3y \]
\[ kx=10+3y \]
\[ kx-10=10+3y-10 \]
\[ kx-10=3y \]
\[ \frac{kx-10}{3}=\frac{3y}{3} \]
\[ \frac{kx-10}{3}=y \]
I hope this helps you understand.

Answer (score 2):

First, isolate $3y$,

$$kx - 10 = 3y$$

Then, divide by $3$ to get $y$:

$$\frac{kx-10}{3} = y$$

Makes sense now?